# Limit average to the most recent records

Tags: mysql

I'd like to limit this query to only calculate the average "duration" of the **last 10** "question" answered by a "student".

```
SELECT question, AVG(duration) AS timeTaken 
FROM t_answer 
WHERE student=2 
GROUP BY question
```

i.e. For a given student, fetch a list of questions answered and the average time it has taken them on their **last 10 attempts** of that question...

```
+----------+-----------+
| question | timeTaken |
+----------+-----------+
| 2        | 3956      |
+----------+-----------+
| 5        | 11102     |
+----------+-----------+
| 9        | 14527     |
+----------+-----------+
```

Sample table data...

```
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| student | question | duration | when                |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1       | 1        | 5301     | 2017-03-10 16:35:11 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2       | 2        | 5217     | 2017-03-10 16:36:51 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 1       | 2        | 3459     | 2017-03-10 16:44:42 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2       | 2        | 2694     | 2017-03-10 16:44:55 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2       | 5        | 11102    | 2017-03-10 16:45:10 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 2       | 9        | 14527    | 2017-03-10 16:45:14 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
| 3       | 5        | 1763     | 2017-03-10 16:45:47 |
+---------+----------+----------+---------------------+
```

Comment: What determines "last 10 attempts"? Post some sample data.

Comment: `last 10 "question"` Do you mean any last 10 question or last 10 unique question?

Comment: Would like to return one row per unique question. Each row displays the average of the last 10 attemps at that question.